# Define custom directive with isolated scope depanding object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have list of Object of person type in my controller when I loop through them it works fine and display name of all person from list.
I have define a controller to display data in structured why but its not allowing to bind scope of custom directive to value of person name
this piece of works fine

```
   <div ng-app="myapp">
                    <div ng-controller="MyController">
                    <div ng-repeat="per in person">
                        <!-- <test user=" -->
                        {{per.firstName}}
                        <!-- "></test> -->
                    </div>
```

But When I try to bind scope of custom directive to object first name ,AngularJS throw error

**Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{per.firstName}}] starting at [{per.firstName}}].**

```
<div ng-repeat="per in person">
                    <test user=" {{per.firstName}}"></test>
                </div>
                </div>

          </div>
```

**AngularJs cond:**

```
var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.controller('MyController',function($scope){
    $scope.person=[
    {firstName:"ali1",
    lastName:"ahmad"
    },
    {firstName:"ali2",
    lastName:"ahmad3"
    },
    {firstName:"ali4",
    lastName:"ahmad"
    },
    {firstName:"ali5",
    lastName:"ahmad"
    },
    ];
});



myapp.directive('test',function(){
    var directive={}
    directive.restrict="E";
    directive.template="Name : {{user.firstName}}";
    directive.scope={
        user:"=user"
    }
    return directive;

});
```

How to bind custom directive with value of object directive.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<test user="per"></test>
```

html:

```
myapp.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            user: '='
        },
        template: 'Name : {{user.firstName}}'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when you bind to a scope you just pass the object, no need for {{}}, so

```
user="per.firstName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
<test user=" {{per.firstName}}"></test>
```

To

```
<test user="person"></test>
```

And use ng-repeat inside the directive.
First send the data from your controller to your directive like this

```
<test user="person"></test>// Here you are sending whole array
```

Then receive your `user` which is containing refrence of `person` 
Then inside your directive receive `user` in some variable as you have done this inside scope of directive  `user: "=user"`

Comment: its not displaying anything